# Why does setf(ios::fixed) skip the 6th number in a double?

Tags: c++

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main() {
     double pi = 0.1234567;
     cout << "1234567890" << endl;
     // cout.width(10);
     cout.setf(ios::fixed);
     cout << pi << endl;
 }
```

outputs

```
1234567890
0.123457
```

Why does it print that instead of 0.123456?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it rounds it correctly, that's why. `0.1234567` rounded to 6 decimal places (the default) is `0.123457`.

Comment: The answer is missing that the default `precision()` of a standard stream is `6`

Comment: @JoergB Yes, I should have not implied that. Fixed.

Comment: @JoergB Is that why when I `cout` a double it prints only the first 6 characters, rounding the last? How could I print a full variable of a double type if it exceeds 6 characters? Set `precision()` to >6?

Comment: Whoops, just read further on in my notes and it says exactly what @JoergB said, thanks guys.